# Refresh Today Widget every time opened

Tags: swift

I thought that Today View every time when i open it it calls "viewWillAppear" but its not. When i change something in my app, and then I slide down for Today View it sometimes refresh the view and sometimes not.

I do all logic in viewWillAppear (fetch data from coreData and put that data to labels), but its not called everytime.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    fetchContent()
    setLabels()
    setContentHeight()
    tableView.reloadData()
    print("view will appear")
}
```

how to call fetchContent and setLabels every time when user opens Today Extensions?

Comment: @BabyAzerty Today Extension is a widget that shows at Today view in Notification Center

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this matter you should be using `NSWidgetProvinding`'s `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`.

Steps:

1.- Make sure that your `UIViewController` implements `NCWidgetProviding`

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding
```

2.- Add the following function:

```
func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

        // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
        // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
        // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
    }
```

3.- In your case you will be using `.NewData`.

Just make sure that you retrieve needed data and refresh your views (*putting every data in place, filling labels, graphs, etc*).

Nevermind the fact that your view is not visible during the call to this function, iOS will fill the view and take a snapshot of it.

Then that's what it shows while you are opening notification center and until you gain control again of your app.

> So, in your case would be something like this:

```
func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        fetchContent()
        setLabels()
        setContentHeight()
        tableView.reloadData()

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer. it works fine on simulator, but not on real device. any ideas why?

Comment: ok i see that if i remove today extension from view notification center and add it again it works well. probably some bug appears.

Comment: how to decide if there is a need to call .newData or .noData? I have three labels to fill from core data. If nothing is filled how do I compare fetched info with displayed yet?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but a question please: what did you mean by "Nevermind the fact that your view is not visible during the call to this function, iOS will fill the view and take a snapshot of it"? 
can you explain more, please? 

because I try your way in my widget, but the app displays the "initial design" on the MainInterface.storboard until they get the data and update the screen, and each time I swipe left right I got the "initial design" until I got the data.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.1 && Xcode 7.2
It looks like some bug appears when you many time recompile this today extension. solution is to remove from notification center and add it again. then it refresh fine everytime opened

Comment: it is only while development process... the same is for widget's title... must remove and add again. Then works fine...